# TCP server that listen on two different ports

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server that is listening on two different ports . I created two different sockets one on port 8888 and one on port 6634. I listen on those ports and then i add the two sockets in FD_SET and pass them to select() function ...
When a socket is ready to read i check with FD_ISSET to see on which port i have message to read .

any way when i connect to port 8888 the conception is successful and i can send towards the server and receive ... when i ctrl+c the client the select function is returning again 1 and now my accept() fails ...
when i do the same thing on port 6634 everything is ok... the code stops at the select() and waits for a socket to be ready to read!

can anyone tell me WHY is this happening ?

take a look at my code in attachment

```
    int main()
    {
        SOCKET          conn_request_skt;   /* socket where connections are accepted */
        char            buf[RBUFLEN], buf1[RBUFLEN];        /* reception buffer */
        uint16_t        lport_n, lport_h, lport_n1, lport_h1;   /* port where the server listens (net/host byte ord resp.) */
        int         bklog = 2;      /* listen backlog */
        SOCKET          s,s1;           
        int         result, n;
        socklen_t addrlen;
        struct sockaddr_in  saddr, caddr;       /* server and client address structures */ 
        int optval,childpid,i; /* flag value for setsockopt */
        int connectcnt; /* number of connection requests */
        fd_set readfds;

        /* Initialize socket API if needed */
        SockStartup();

        /* input server port number */
        lport_h=6634;
        lport_n = htons(lport_h);
        lport_h1=8888;
        lport_n1 = htons(lport_h1);

        /* create the socket */
        printf("Creating first socket\n");
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
            err_fatal("socket() failed");
        printf("done, socket number %u\n",s);

        /* bind the socket to any local IP address */
        saddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        saddr.sin_port        = lport_n;
        saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        showAddr("Binding to address first socket", &saddr);
        result = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(saddr));
        if (result == -1)
            err_fatal("bind() failed");
        printf("done.\n");

        printf("Creating second socket\n");
        s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (s1 == INVALID_SOCKET)
            err_fatal("socket() failed");
        printf("done, socket number %u\n",s1);

        /* bind the socket to any local IP address */

        saddr.sin_port=lport_n1;

        showAddr("Binding to address second socket", &saddr);
        result = bind(s1, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(saddr));
        if (result == -1)
            err_fatal("bind() failed");
        printf("done.\n");


        /* listen */
        printf ("Listening at socket %d with backlog = %d \n",s,bklog);
        result = listen(s, bklog);
        if (result == -1)
            err_fatal("listen() failed");
        printf("done.\n");

        printf ("Listening at socket %d with backlog = %d \n",s1,bklog);
        result = listen(s1, bklog);
        if (result == -1)
            err_fatal("listen() failed");
        printf("done.\n");
for (;;)
    {


        FD_ZERO(&readfds);          /* initialize the fd set */
        FD_SET(s, &readfds);
        FD_SET(s1, &readfds); /* add socket fd */
        printf("here \n");

        printf("result bifore select is %d \n", result);
        result=select(s1+1, &readfds, 0, 0, 0);

        printf("result after select is %d \n", result);

        if(result<0)
            {
                err_fatal("select() failed");

            }
        if(result>0)
        {

            if(FD_ISSET(s,&readfds))
            {

                conn_request_skt=s;
                /* accept next connection */
                addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                s = accept(conn_request_skt, (struct sockaddr *) &caddr, &addrlen);
                if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
                err_fatal("accept() failed");
                showAddr("Accepted connection from", &caddr);
                printf("new socket: %u\n",s);
                /* serve the client on socket s */
                for (;;)
                {
                    n=recv(s, buf, RBUFLEN-1, 0);
                    if (n < 0)
                    {
                        printf("Read error\n");
                        closesocket(s);
                        printf("Socket %d closed\n", s);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (n==0)
                    {
                        printf("Connection closed by party on socket %d\n",s);
                        //closesocket(s);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Received line from socket %03d :\n", s);
                        buf[n]=0;
                        printf("[%s]\n",buf);
                        if(writen(s, buf, n) != n)
                        printf("Write error while replying\n");
                        else
                        printf("Reply sent\n");
                    }   
                }
            }


            if(FD_ISSET(s1,&readfds))
            {
                conn_request_skt=s1;
                /* accept next connection */
                addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                printf("bifore accept! \n");
                s1 = accept(conn_request_skt, (struct sockaddr *) &caddr, &addrlen);
                if (s1 == INVALID_SOCKET)
                err_fatal("accept() failed");
                showAddr("Accepted connection from", &caddr);
                printf("new socket: %u\n",s1);
                /* serve the client on socket s */
                for (;;)
                {
                    n=recv(s1, buf, RBUFLEN-1, 0);
                    if (n < 0)
                    {
                        printf("Read error\n");
                        closesocket(s1);
                        printf("Socket %d closed\n", s1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (n==0)
                    {
                        printf("Connection closed by party on socket %d\n",s1);
                        //closesocket(s);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Received line from socket %03d :\n", s1);
                        buf[n]=0;
                        printf("[%s]\n",buf);
                        if(writen(s1, buf, n) != n)
                        printf("Write error while replying\n");
                        else
                        printf("Reply sent\n");
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first listener socket is created with:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

And then the data socket is accepted with:

```
 conn_request_skt=s;
 s = accept(conn_request_skt, (struct sockaddr *) &caddr, &addrlen);
```

See? The next loop, when you are going to select over the listener socket, `s` no longer holds that socket, but the (closed) data socket.

The solution is to use different variables for the listener socket and the data socket (`conn_request_skt` is just obfuscating the issue).

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your socket variable s1 with the result of the accept() call. So s1 contains now the descriptor of the socket you are actually reading from. Then you close that socket. But in the next pass of the main loop, you check for readability on that (now closed) descriptor, which does not work.

I believe it would be better not to reuse variables in this case. Use a new variable for the actual connection socket, so that you retain the original listening socket in s1.